# Attempting to setup C++ project using CEDET/EDE

Tags: c++, emacs24, cedet

I have a couple C++ projects that I am working on. I have been using semantic for the sake of autocompletion. However, I want to make better use of the tools out there.

I have the following directory structure

- project/

  - Makefile
  - src/

    - my .cpp and .h files
    - couple_other_directories/
  - test/

    - my test files

I currently have the following in my .emacs

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/vendor/cedet-bzr/cedet-devel-load.el")

(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semanticdb-minor-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-local-symbol-highlight-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-completions-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-summary-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-show-parser-state-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-highlight-edits-mode)
(semantic-mode 1)
(require 'semantic/ia)

(require 'semantic/bovine/clang)

;; PROJECTS

(global-ede-mode t)

(ede-cpp-root-project "MyProject"
                      :name "My Project"
                      :file "/path/to/project/Makefile"
                      :include-path '("/path/to/first/includes"
                                      "/path/to/second/include")
                      :system-include-path '()
                      :spp-table '())
```

Whenever I have the project open, and `C-c . g` I get an error in the mini-buffer `Method project-rescan called on nil` Which prevents me from scanning all of my source files for the sake of auto-completion.

What am I doing wrong here?

I've been attempting to follow Alex Ott's [A Gentle Introduction to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) but it does not seem to mention anything about this error.

I'm also using CEDET from bazaar.

This is what my `M-x cedet-version` looks like.

```
CEDET Version:  2.0
                    Requested   File        Loaded
  Package           Version     Version     Version
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  cedet:            2.0         ok          ok
  eieio:            1.4         ok          ok
  semantic:         2.2         ok          ok
  srecode:          1.2         ok          ok
  ede:              1.2         ok          ok
  cogre:            1.2         ok          Not Loaded
  cedet-contrib:    1.2         nil         Not Loaded
```

Answer (score 1):

The keybinding `C-c . g` which is bound to `ede-rescan-toplevel` is for scanning project definition data and not for parsing your source files.  Since the `ede-cpp-root-project` doesn't have definition data in the project, it never implemented that function.

If you visit a source file, that source file will get parsed as needed.  It will also find your includes and parse as needed.  Also, if you just wait around a little bit, it will reparse all the files near the one you are editing in idle time, so that by the time you need it, the data should be around.